# Vaadin 6 and maven integration results in 404 resource not available error

Tags: maven, vaadin

Im developing a vaadin hello user application with vaadin 6.8.5 jar. It works fine. But when i convert the project to maven it shows **404 HTTP status report with error as resource not available.**
Please suggest any ideas to fix this issue.

**My Vaadin application**

```
public class Testsample extends Application {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void init() {
    Window mainWindow = new Window("Sampletest Application");
    Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");
    mainWindow.addComponent(label);
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Testsample Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin application class to start</description>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.services.TestsampleApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Testsample Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Regards,
M.Vignesh

Answer (score 0):

Your application class in web.xml hava name **SampletestApplication**:

```
<param-value>com.example.services.SampletestApplication</param-value>
```

And in your example aplication class have name **Testsample** :

```
public class Testsample extends Application {
```

They should have the same name.

Comment: Its my typing mistake now edited please suggest me a solution

Comment: it is a sample application just displaying the message . The application class code is given and thats it.

Comment: Do you have had a look at the servlet engine log files? Probably it is throwing an error on context startup